# Get all project pipeline details using gitlab api

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Below is the gitLab api endpoint used to get pipeline details for the project (id: 1)
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipelines

Suppose in a gitLab group (id: 2) I have 6 projects (id range 1-6).

How can I retrieve the pipeline status for all the projects present in the group (id: 12), in a single call? instead of making multiple calls (number of projects present in the group)

Comment: That's not possible, Gitlab API doesn't work like that. You need to get all the project id from the group and iterate over them to get pipelines statuses.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operation in the current REST API to get all pipelines for either all projects, or for multiple projects, only one at a time. Although the REST API is eventually being replaced by GraphQL (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/), it unfortunately will not have an operation to do this either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Gitlab GraphQL API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/getting_started.html).

You can use the [`Group` query](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/index.html#querygroup) to fetch your group and then specify that you want the `projects > pipelines > status` fields:

```
{
  group(fullPath: "gitlab-org") {
    id
    name
    projects {
      nodes {
        name
        pipelines {
          nodes {
            id
            status
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `fullPath` value above should be your group's slug.